# Android Application: I have two forms within my app which need to save to a database

Tags: java, android, database, json, navigation

The first form is saving to the Database perfectly fine.  I am trying to test if the second form saves to the database, however, the second form appears if a checkbox is checked on the first form; the second form appears and disappears almost immediately.  Can someone help please?

First Form java code

package com.lifematters;

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MoodTracker extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// url to create new 
private static String url_create_mood =    "http://depressionapp.net46.net/depressionapp/moodtracker.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    EditText autoDate, autoTime, inputPlace, inputMood, causeFactor, inputFactor;

CheckBox checkTreatment;

Button btnSave;

String sAutoDate;
    String sAutoTime; 
    String sInputPlace; 
    String sInputMood;  
    String sCauseFactor;
    String sInputFactor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mood_tracker);

    autoDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoDate);
    autoTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoTime);
    inputPlace = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPlace);
    inputMood = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMood);
    causeFactor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chooseFactor);
    inputFactor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFactor);

    // Create button
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    checkTreatment = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkTreatment);
    // create user
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            sAutoDate = autoDate.getText().toString();
            sAutoTime = autoTime.getText().toString(); 
            sInputPlace = inputPlace.getText().toString(); 
            sInputMood = inputMood.getText().toString();  
            sCauseFactor = autoDate.getText().toString();
            sInputFactor = inputFactor.getText().toString(); 


            //if any field is empty, display toast
            if (sAutoDate.matches("") || sInputMood.matches("") || 
                    sCauseFactor.matches("")) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please ensure all fields marked with asterisks are completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                new CreateMoodTracker().execute();


            }

            CheckBox checkTreatment = (CheckBox ) findViewById(R.id.checkTreatment);
            if ( checkTreatment.isChecked() ) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TreatmentTracker.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } 
            }
          });
        }

        /**
         * Background Asynchronous Task 
         * */
        class CreateMoodTracker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        int success;

        /**
        * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
        * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MoodTracker.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Tracker Record...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating user
         * */
         protected String doInBackground(String... args) {



        sAutoDate = autoDate.getText().toString();
        sAutoTime = autoTime.getText().toString(); 
        sInputPlace = inputPlace.getText().toString(); 
        sInputMood = inputMood.getText().toString();  
        sCauseFactor = causeFactor.getText().toString();
        sInputFactor = inputFactor.getText().toString(); 

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UID", "1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", sAutoDate));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", sAutoTime));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("place", sInputPlace));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mood", sInputMood));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("causefactor", sCauseFactor));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("factordetail", sInputFactor));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create URL accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_mood,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat from response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString()); 

        // check for success tag
        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created , move to login screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();

             } else {
                // failed to create
             }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
           }

          /**
          * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
          * **/
           protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
           // dismiss the dialog once done
          pDialog.dismiss();

           }
           }

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the value of checkbox from the first form to second form whether checkbox is true or false.Then control the value.

Comment: I figured it out; it was navigating to the treatment form but then closing as I had it coded to return back to the MainActivity upon saving:

        if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created , move to login screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();